# Why my function does not run <object>

Tags: javascript, php, html

In `index.php` i run function two times, which include `chart.html`.

index.php

```
chart_line($valuesNight);     //run function for the first time
chart_line($valuesEvening);   //run function for the second time
?>
<?php function chart_line($jsonDataSource){ ?>
                <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var dataSource = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonDataSource ?>');
        var dValues = new Array;
        var dTimeDate = new Array;

        for(var o in dataSource) {
            dValues.push(dataSource[o]['dValue']);
            dTimeDate.push(dataSource[o]['dTimeDate']);
        }
        console.log('dValues', dValues);
        // store values
        sessionStorage.setItem('myValues', JSON.stringify(dValues));
        sessionStorage.setItem('myTime', JSON.stringify(dTimeDate));

    </script>     //include chart.html
            <object type="text/html" data="chart.html" width="100%"  height="420"></object>
                </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

When `chart_line($valuesNight);` runs `console.log('dValues', dValues);` returns right values, but it does not run this `object` with `chart.html`. Then `chart_line($valuesEvening);` runs and `console dvalues` returns evening data. After that `chart.html` starts two times and both times gives me latest (evening) data. How can i fix this problem?

chart.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

// retrieve value
var myTime = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('myTime'));
var myValuesStr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('myValues'));

var myValues = myValuesStr.map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});

console.log('myTime', myTime);
console.log('myValues', myValues);

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        //  ...
    });
});
        </script>

<script src="js/charts.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.src.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Console executes in this order:**

```
console.log('dValues', dValues); // from index.php  - night values
    // HERE SHOUD EXECUTE CONSOLE FROM CHART.HTML
console.log('dValues', dValues); // from index.php  - evening values

console.log('myTime', myTime);      // from chart.html  - evening values
console.log('myValues', myValues);  // from chart.html  - evening values
console.log('myTime', myTime);      // from chart.html  - evening values
console.log('myValues', myValues);  // from chart.html  - evening values
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to replace `$(function () {` with `$(document).ready(function {`. It may be the case that your function is executed before your container div has been created. And I think your external scripts should be loaded BEFORE your inline code is defined.

Comment: @steven `$(function()` is short for `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: are you really sure @DamienPirsy? Isn't it a immediate execution?

Comment: So you think that i should put script after `<div id="container">`?

Comment: I think the execution order is not what you expect - it seems to execute the method with the evening values before it starts rendering the HTML from the object tag and the sessionStorage data gets overwritten. I couldn't find information on if the object tag is supposed to load HTML synchronously or asynchronously, but I'm guessing it's a race condition there.

I would try including the HTML page with PHP's include/require (instead of the object tag) on the server side, that way the HTML is definitely there before the scripts execute.

Comment: Are you loading jquery inside chart.html? in this example I don't see it and `$(function () ...)` won't run without jquery. And one more note, this: `var dataSource = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonDataSource ?>');` can be changed just to `var dataSource = <?php echo $jsonDataSource ?>;`, JSON is Java Script Object Notation, it is valid JS directly (and if it is not then JSON.parse will throw anyway)

Comment: When i do `<?php include('chart.html'); ?>`, console executes in right order, but i get error like is loaded twice in the same page, so probably i should load my function separate somehow? @lupatus Yes, in `chart.html` i run `chart.js`, it returns previous error. Thanks for `parse`

Comment: With one chart works fine (both `<?php include('g-basic.htm'); ?>` and `object` ). But not with two.

Comment: if you mean `include()` case it's because of `#container` - you cannot have 2 nodes with same `id` - with include it'll be in same html / js scope (with `object` it's like in iframe)

Comment: What about, if i run `chart1.html` for `night` and `chart2.html` for `evening`? I know it's bad solution, but would it work?

Comment: It's not very elegant, but I believe that would work, provided you save your night and evening data in different sessionStorage items. And also what @lupatus said, can't have two elements with the same ID on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary solution, but it works:

```
//for valuesNight
$(function () {
    $('#container1').
//...
<div id="container1">

//for valuesEvening
$(function () {
    $('#container2').
//...
<div id="container2">
```